# Databinding the ListBox SelectedItems attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listbox

I know that the ListBox has both a SelectedItem and SelectedItems attribute and that only the SelectedItem attribute can be used with databinding. However, I've read in multiple locations that by setting up a setter like so

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
     </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and then by adding the following property

```
public IEnumerable<Item> SelectedItems
{
     get
     {
          return Items.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
     }
}
```

I can use the SelectedItems property to get the all items that were selected. I mainly have two questions regarding this:

1. Where does the Item and Items in the property come from? I've not been able to find a using directive that will remove the error preventing me from using it.
2. Is this the recommended way to do what I'm trying to achieve. If not, then what would you recommend?

Oh, before I forget I thought I should mention that I'm using both MVVM Light and Fody's PropertyChanged.

Comment: Here, `Item` is a data item class in the view model. It should have an `IsSelected` property, which you can bind the ListBoxItem.IsSelected property to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the articles and their exact solution for doing so but my speculations is this:

1. The whole page has a ViewModel named `MyPageViewModel`.
2. `MyPageViewModel` has an `ObservableCollection` named `Items`.
3. `Item` is ViewModel type (derived from `DependencyObject`)
4. `Item` has a `DependencyProperty` named `IsSelected`

Given these assumptions you can see where can all things fit.

---

If the DataContext of the whole page is `MyPageViewModel`, then in this xaml code first `IsSelected` refers to a property of `ListBoxItem`, and the second one refers to a property in ViewModel of `Item`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
         </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
//This is inside MyPageViewModel
//Item is a ViewModel type
public IEnumerable<Item> SelectedItems
{
     get
     {
          //Items is ObservableCollection<Item>
          return Items.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
     }
}

//This is also inside MyPageViewModel
private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get { return _items; } }
```

---

The whole scenario can go the other way too. I mean it can be implemented in View instead of ViewModel. Maybe derive from ListBox and override a few things including `SelectedItems`. But adding these sorts of complexities are better done to ViewModel than View.